# RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasSgemm( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, &beta, c, ldc

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using ubuntu 20.04, torch==1.7.1

I am building a Deep reinforcement learning agent using pytorch. Everything works fine until today where while training outputs error as stated above. Weird thing is that this happens few days back and got fixed when I restarted my computer. This time restarting did not fix it.

Another weird thing is when run my script in terminal it outputs `RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling cublasSgemm( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, &beta, c, ldc`

however when I use debugging in pycharm it outputs different error: `RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered` The error seems to arise when I pass input into first fully connect layer.

```
  File "MYPATH/fc.py", line 33, in forward
    x = F.elu(self.fc1(inputs))
  File "MYPATH/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1227, in elu
    result = torch._C._nn.elu(input, alpha)
```

And as I was writing this question running my script on terminal outputs `RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered`